# UITapGesture only works after reLoad UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 1 year works with Objective-C and is my first question that I make because I always found the answer in this site, but this situation is completely insane and did not found anything similar.

I have a custom class (called BallClass from UIView). The UIView have an UIImageView inside on it and a UITapGesture to make an action.

So when I create the object in a UIViewController, does not works the tapAction when press in the object, but if I change to other screen and return it, the tapGesture works perfect.

I tried many options, but I cant makes work in the first load.

I work with ARC, Xcode (4.6.3) and OSX (10.8.4) and IB but this objects was created with no IB .

Thanks in advance.

Here is the class BallClass.m

```
    - (void)tapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
            NSLog(@"hola");
    }

    - (id)initBall:(CGRect)frame {
           if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
           // Initialization code

           // Recibir las variables iniciales para el control del timer
           ball = [[Ball alloc] init];

           // Agregar la imagen de la pelota en el view
          UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
          [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([self bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([self bounds]))];
          [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
          [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pelota.png"]];
          [imageView setTag:100];
          [imageView setNeedsDisplay];

         // Add TAP
          UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
         // Tap Properties
        [tapGesture setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
        [tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [tapGesture setDelegate:(id)self];
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

        [self addSubview:imageView];

        [self setNeedsDisplay];

         // Propiedades del View
       [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
       self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self setTag:100];

       // BALL BOUNCE
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 / 30.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];        
      }

      return self;
      }

    - (void)onTimer:(NSTimer *)timerLocal {
        // Do something
     }

    ... // more methods
```

Here is the instantiate:

```
       ballView00 = [[BallView alloc] initBall:CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)];
```

The UiView show perfect, and the animation works fine, but the UITapGesture just works, as mentioned early, after reLoad the ViewController.

Here is the link to image the Ball and UIView (@kBall). Sorry, about image, but I cant load until I have 10 points :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The ball make a spin with this:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5f
                      delay: 0.0f
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations: ^{
                     self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, M_PI / 2);
                 }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         if (animating) {
                             // if flag still set, keep spinning with constant speed
                             [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                         }
                    }
                 }];
```

And generate conflict with the main timer. I change the spin action with simple add            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, M_PI / 2); inside drawRect method in the class.

**Apparently, I can't nested two timers, because "disable" the tapGesture, so when I change of the screen and return, the spin was stopped and this help to found this situation.**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the superview's frame. What view is holding ballView00? Does ballView lie entirely within it's superview's bounds?

Usually when you encounter problem where you're expecting a touch but don't get it it's because the view set to receive the touch is outside one of its parents' bounds.

So if the superview bounds are 100x100 and the ball is at x=125 y=125 it will not receive a touch.

A lot of magic happens when your views get laid out, it's not surprising to sometimes find one with 0x0 dimensions because of some incorrect constraints.

You can easily check the bounds of all your views by giving them a background color.

Comment: Good idea @kball, let me check and I return later with results.

Comment: unfortunately still the same problem. I reconfigure my ImageView but does not work. Actually I update my UIImageView configuration code above and add the image of the ball and UIView with black background.